# Copy data from one table to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables one is not associated with my rails application `invtypes` and `items` table which is associated with my application.

Table `invtypes` has 20.000 records that i need to move to `items` table.

Now my first attempt was to simply do a ActiveRecord query on invtypes to get all entries and then go over each entry and create a new `Item` by instantiating a new `Item model` adding attributes and then calling `model.save`

However this also does validation and few other things that slow down making this a 30min task executed in `Rails Console` since i will be doing this a few times i can't have it be so slow.

So my second idea was to try this with plain old query no Models however this now gives an error:

```
  ←[1m←[35m (27.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO items (typeID, name, description, volume, price, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (0, '#System', '', 0.0, 0.0, '20
13-03-29 04:06:27 +0100', '2013-03-29 04:06:27 +0100');
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect datetime value: '2013-03-29 04:06:27 +0100' for column 'created_at' at row 1: INSERT INTO ite
ms (typeID, name, description, volume, price, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (0, '#System', '', 0.0, 0.0, '2013-03-29 04:06:27 +0100', '2013-03-29 04:
06:27 +0100');
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:2
33:in `query'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:2
33:in `block in execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in
`block in log'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrume
nt'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in
`log'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:2
33:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:214:in `e
xecute'
        from (irb):21:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):19:in `each'
        from (irb):19
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Due to Time.now

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all( "SELECT * FROM invtypes" )
time = Time.now
result.each do |row|
 sql = "INSERT INTO items (typeID, name, description, volume, price, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (#{row["typeID"]}, '#{row["typeName"]}', '#{row["description"]}', #{row["volume"]}, #{row["basePrice"]}, '#{time}', '#{time}');"
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

How can i go about this with Ruby/Rails or should I write a app in Java | C to execute this query ?

Only executes 10 rows then throws:

```
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:2
33:in `query'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:2
33:in `block in execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in
`block in log'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrume
nt'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in
`log'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:2
33:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:214:in `e
xecute'
        from (irb):7:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):4:in `each'
        from (irb):4
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
time = Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db)
```

Comment: Problem with this is that for some reason it only makes 10 records then stops and returns an error i added the error to the bottom of my question.

Comment: I don't see the error, but just the stack. Could you include the error itself?

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries and inserts within a loop are slow. Try with `INSERT..SELECT`, that command will insert all the rows that you selected with the second statement. I don't know what DB are you using, but for example, if you are using MySQL you can take a look at [the documentation of the statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).